# Gitconfig: Permission denied

Tags: git, bash

I wanted to edit my `.gitconfig` file to change the default editor.

I typed `$HOME/.gitconfig` to set the correct directory and got

`-bash: /Users/Myself/.gitconfig: Permission denied`.

Why does it happen and what does it mean? How do I get past it?

(OS X Yosemite 10.10.4)

Comment: It sounds like you tried to execute the file... you probably wanted to pass that to an editor, e.g. `emacs $HOME/.gitconfig`. The permission denied here is because the file is not set to be executable (nor should it be).

Comment: Lol so many enthusiasts. When I published my answer I didn't see the comment.

Comment: @FatalError should really post that as an answer, given you were the first.

Comment: Promise to put +1 if @FatalError does, hehe. Call me if he does please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have permission to access `$HOME/.gitconfig`. Use `open "$HOME/.gitconfig"` to open the file in your default text viewer.

Comment: I accepted this answer with the proviso that if [FatalError](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1172428/fatalerror) adds his comment as an answer, I will accept his/her instead.

Comment: @Ursus, ye I knew that. If he does, knock me here, I don't want to steal his reputation.

Comment: I have change .gitconfig, but I don't understand what do I have to change in it ?
I am trying to push my android project on BitBucket. 
I have made a repo on it. But I can't understand which is the next thing to do .

Answer (score 4):

Just use git command :

```
git config --global core.editor your-favorite-editor
```

`--global` instructs git to change your global config (effectively stored in $HOME/.gitconfig), adding the following line in the [core] section :

```
editor=your-favorite-editor
```

You can add it by hand; but for that, as said by others, you mustn't try to *execute* $HOME/.gitconfig, but you have to *open* it (with a text editor)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to *edit* that file, you should *launch an editor* and open the file with it.

If you type a file name as a command in a UNIX shell, the OS will try to *run* that file as a program, but your `.gitconfig` doesn't have exec permissions - that's the error you see.

You can try running `$EDITOR $HOME/.gitconfig`, which could get expanded to something like `vim ~/.gitconfig` (or whatever editor you have in your `$EDITOR` env variable).